# Going through the database using cursors, something missing?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to create a news reader app where the contents of the news are retrieved from an api using JSON and stored in an ListView so that the users can see the different titles of articles.
I have created 2 AsyncTask :

The first one is used to retrieve the list of article Ids of the Top Stories from a JSONArray.I retrieve each individual article Id using a for loop that runs 10 times to get 10 article Ids.

The second AsyncTask is called inside the first one. I need to pass another url in the second AsyncTask using the article's specific Id in order to get the articleId, title and link which I want to INSERT into the "articleId" "title" and "url" column of my table.

I'm having a problem displaying the contents of the table.
What I'm aiming for is that only after all the 10 rows have been populated thanks to the AsynTask, that I show the contents of my table once.

This is what my Code looks like now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DownloadIdList idTask;
DownloadArticle articleTask;
SQLiteDatabase newsReaderDB;

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> articlesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    idTask = new DownloadIdList();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, articlesList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    try {

        newsReaderDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        newsReaderDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topStories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, articleId INT(10), title VARCHAR, url VARCHAR)");

        //newsReaderDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE topStories");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Database deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }   catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't create or open Database On Create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    try {

        idTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");

    }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't download URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public class DownloadIdList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>    {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1)  {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return result;

        }catch (Exception e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't get Top Stories Id's" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONArray idArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)    {

                int value = idArray.getInt(i);
                Log.i("Top Stories Id", String.valueOf(value));
                String id = String.valueOf(value);

                articleTask = new DownloadArticle();

                    try {
                        articleTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + id + ".json?print=pretty");


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"can't get article info from id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
            }

        }catch (JSONException e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't get JSON Object",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}

public class DownloadArticle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String content = "";

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                content += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return content;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get Articles after retrieving the id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        super.onPostExecute(content);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);

            int idInfo = jsonObject.getInt("id");
            String title = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("title"));
            title = title.replaceAll("'","''");
            String urlien = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("url"));


            //newsReaderDB = openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            newsReaderDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO topStories (articleId, title, url) VALUES(" + idInfo + ", '" + title + "','" + urlien + "');");
            showData();


        }catch (JSONException   e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get Article", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}

/*public void showDatabase()  {

    try {

        newsReaderDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = newsReaderDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM topStories", null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");

        int a_idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("articleId");

        int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");

        int urlIndex = c.getColumnIndex("url");

        c.moveToFirst();

        while (c != null ) {

            Log.i("Id", String.valueOf(c.getInt(idIndex)));
            Log.i("Article id", String.valueOf(c.getInt(a_idIndex)));
            Log.i("Title", c.getString(titleIndex));
            Log.i("Url Link", c.getString(urlIndex));

            c.moveToNext();
        }

    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to List Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}*/

public void showData()  {
try {
    Cursor cursor = newsReaderDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM topStories", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            String a_id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("articleId")));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
            String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url"));

            Log.i("id", id);
            Log.i("article id", a_id);
            Log.i("title", title);
            Log.i("url", url);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } cursor.close();
}catch (Exception e)    {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

The output is :

```
    10-15 12:23:42.755 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713249
    10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12711343
    10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12711511
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713056
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12709220
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12707606
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12712577
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12709820
    10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12712454
    10-15 12:23:43.013 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 1
    10-15 12:23:43.013 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:43.013 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: KiCad: A commitment to freedom
    10-15 12:23:43.013 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://giving.web.cern.ch/content/kicad-development-1
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 1
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: KiCad: A commitment to freedom
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://giving.web.cern.ch/content/kicad-development-1
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 2
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713249
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: What has happened down here is the winds have changed
    10-15 12:23:43.259 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://andrewgelman.com/2016/09/21/what-has-happened-down-here-is-the-winds-have-changed/
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 1
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: KiCad: A commitment to freedom
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://giving.web.cern.ch/content/kicad-development-1
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 2
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713249
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: What has happened down here is the winds have changed
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://andrewgelman.com/2016/09/21/what-has-happened-down-here-is-the-winds-have-changed/
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 3
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12711343
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: A single byte write opened a root execution exploit
    10-15 12:23:43.467 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/10/14/a-single-byte-write-opened-a-root-execution-exploit/
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 1
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: KiCad: A commitment to freedom
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://giving.web.cern.ch/content/kicad-development-1
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 2
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713249
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: What has happened down here is the winds have changed
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://andrewgelman.com/2016/09/21/what-has-happened-down-here-is-the-winds-have-changed/
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 3
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12711343
    10-15 12:23:43.722 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: A single byte write opened a root execution exploit
    10-15 12:23:43.723 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/10/14/a-single-byte-write-opened-a-root-execution-exploit/
    10-15 12:23:43.723 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 4
    10-15 12:23:43.723 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12711511
    10-15 12:23:43.723 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: Books Programmers Don't Really Read (2008)
    10-15 12:23:43.723 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://www.billthelizard.com/2008/12/books-programmers-dont-really-read.html
    10-15 12:23:43.909 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for url
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.iboundiaye.newsreader.MainActivity$DownloadArticle.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:216)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.iboundiaye.newsreader.MainActivity$DownloadArticle.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:161)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    10-15 12:23:43.910 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    10-15 12:23:43.914 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    10-15 12:23:43.914 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

and then it continues giving a set of incremented data until article 9.
At this point it should give until article 10 but for some reason, it finds it null so it skips one set and shows until article 9.

My desired output is:

```
10-15 12:23:42.755 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713089
10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713249
10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12711343
10-15 12:23:42.756 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12711511
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12713056
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12709220
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12707606
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12712577
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12709820
10-15 12:23:42.757 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Top Stories Id: 12712454
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 1
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713089
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: KiCad: A commitment to freedom
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://giving.web.cern.ch/content/kicad-development-1
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 2
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12713249
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: What has happened down here is the winds have changed
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://andrewgelman.com/2016/09/21/what-has-happened-down-here-is-the-winds-have-changed/
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 3
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12711343
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: A single byte write opened a root execution exploit
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/10/14/a-single-byte-write-opened-a-root-execution-exploit/
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 4
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12711511
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: Books Programmers Don't Really Read (2008)
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://www.billthelizard.com/2008/12/books-programmers-dont-really-read.html
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 5
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12709220
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: Intel will add deep-learning instructions to its processors
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://lemire.me/blog/2016/10/14/intel-will-add-deep-learning-instructions-to-its-processors/
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 6
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12707606
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: Be Kind
    10-15 12:23:45.109 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://www.briangilham.com/blog/2016/10/10/be-kind
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 7
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12712577
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: The Ops Identity Crisis
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://www.susanjfowler.com/blog/2016/10/13/the-ops-identity-crisis
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 8
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12709820
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: Easy Amazon EC2 Instance Comparison
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: http://www.ec2instances.info/
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/id: 9
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/article id: 12712454
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/title: 5900 online stores found skimming
    10-15 12:23:45.110 32635-32635/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/url: https://gwillem.github.io/2016/10/11/5900-online-stores-found-skimming/
```

(With article 10 included at the end)

Comment: if insert is not working you will get some exception in logs paste that

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it doesn't actually, it just returns the database with null in the title and url columns

Comment: so the primary key is auto generated ? and you want to insert in the same row i.e  you want to update(first insert row) in second insert or insert another new row?

Comment: Yes the primary key is auto generated. And after I have inserted the articleId in the first row using the postExecute of the first AsyncTask, I want to insert the title and the url in the same row as the articleId which has been inserted in the first AsyncTask using the postExecute of the second AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DownloadIdList idTask;
DownloadArticle articleTask;
SQLiteDatabase newsReaderDB;

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> articlesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    idTask = new DownloadIdList();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, articlesList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    try {

        newsReaderDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        newsReaderDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topStories (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, articleId INT(10), title VARCHAR, url VARCHAR)");

        //newsReaderDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE topStories");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Database deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }   catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't create or open Database On Create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


    try {

        idTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");

    }   catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't download URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

public class DownloadIdList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>    {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1)  {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return result;

        }catch (Exception e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't get Top Stories Id's" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {

            JSONArray idArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)    {

                int value = idArray.getInt(i);
                Log.i("Top Stories Id", String.valueOf(value));
                String id = String.valueOf(value);
                idList.add(id);
              /*  articleTask = new DownloadArticle();

                    try {
                        articleTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + id + ".json?print=pretty");


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"can't get article info from id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }*/
            }
for(int l=0;l<idList.size();l++){
    articleTask = new DownloadArticle();
i = l;
                    try {
                        articleTask.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + id + ".json?print=pretty");


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"can't get article info from id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
}
        }catch (JSONException e)    {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Can't get JSON Object",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}

public class DownloadArticle extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String content = "";

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                content += current;

                data = reader.read();

            }

            return content;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get Articles after retrieving the id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        super.onPostExecute(content);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);

            int idInfo = jsonObject.getInt("id");
            String title = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("title"));
            title = title.replaceAll("'","''");
            String urlien = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("url"));


            //newsReaderDB = openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            newsReaderDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO topStories (articleId, title, url) VALUES(" + idInfo + ", '" + title + "','" + urlien + "');");
            if(i==(idList.size()-1){//last row is inserted in db
                 showData();
            }



        }catch (JSONException   e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get Article", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}

/*public void showDatabase()  {

    try {

        newsReaderDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("News", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c = newsReaderDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM topStories", null);

        c.moveToFirst();

        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");

        int a_idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("articleId");

        int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");

        int urlIndex = c.getColumnIndex("url");

        c.moveToFirst();

        while (c != null ) {

            Log.i("Id", String.valueOf(c.getInt(idIndex)));
            Log.i("Article id", String.valueOf(c.getInt(a_idIndex)));
            Log.i("Title", c.getString(titleIndex));
            Log.i("Url Link", c.getString(urlIndex));

            c.moveToNext();
        }

    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to List Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}*/

public void showData()  {
try {
    Cursor cursor = newsReaderDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM topStories", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            String a_id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("articleId")));
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
            String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url"));

            Log.i("id", id);
            Log.i("article id", a_id);
            Log.i("title", title);
            Log.i("url", url);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } cursor.close();
}catch (Exception e)    {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, it does make more sense this way!
But it still won't let me store the url now : I've added a e.printStackTrace() at the catch of the now UPDATE statement.
But it shows this errororg.json.JSONException: No value for url

Comment: Thank you, it does make more sense this way! But it still won't let me store the url now : I've added a e.printStackTrace() at the catch of the now UPDATE statement. But it shows this error "org.json.JSONException: No value for url".
The value at that url is " http://petapixel.com/2016/10/11/cooled-nikon-d5500a-chills-sensor-clearer-star-photos/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%25253A+PetaPixel+%252528PetaPixel%252529".

Is it because of the plus signs in the link? should I escape them?

Comment: U can store it as a string instead of URL and paste your update query as well

Comment: The advice you gave me about UPDATE helped me realize a lot of things :
- I don't need to use a cursor in the for loop of the first postExecute.
- I don't need to store the article id at this point:

Comment: newsReaderDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO topStories (articleId) VALUES(" + id + ")");

Comment: I'm sorry for these comments, I instinctively hit the enter key to go to a new line when I should be doing SHIFT + ENTER...

The advice you gave me about UPDATE helped me realize a lot of things : 
- I don't need to use a cursor in the for loop of the first postExecute. 
- I don't need to INSERT the article id at this point:
    newsReaderDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO topStories (articleId) VALUES(" + id + ")");

Comment: I can just do it in one go with the tile and url once I retrieve them from the JSON object:
    newsReaderDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO topStories (articleId, title, url) VALUES(" + idInfo + ", '" + title + "','" + urlien + "');");

Makes things clearer actually but it seems that it still isn't storing into the database because now it does indeed go until the showDatabase function but the error is now :
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
which I think means there is still no data in the DATABASE...

Comment: I don't know if you understand so I'm going to edit the code up there so you can see a bit clearer...

Comment: Alright, now that I run the code a second time, I can see the results, so it does indeed store it into the database, but it seems that the cursor is what is giving me an issue when trying to show the items in the database.

It shows a CursorIndexOutofBoundsException: Index 10 requested, with a size of 10

after displaying the list of 10 rows in the database with all the necessary info I need.

I think it is still trying to go through the database when it is actually the end of the rows in the database, do you have any idea how i could fix that?

Comment: first you are calling insert only once and you are calling method showdatabase() method before inserting values into it .you are calling your first insert in second webservice call so in post execute of that after insert statment you should call showDatabase method()

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Well if you do that, it's going be part of the for loop you see so it will run the showDatabase method 10 times.

10-14 14:44:42.290 7924-7924/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Id: 1
10-14 14:44:42.290 7924-7924/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Article id: 12707606
10-14 14:44:42.290 7924-7924/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Title: Be Kind
10-14 14:44:42.290 7924-7924/com.iboundiaye.newsreader I/Url Link: https://www.briangilham.com/blog/2016/10/10/be-kind

then CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException index 0 req with size of 0

Then info of 2nd article then exception at index 1 size 1

Comment: and keeps going until you get the 10 articles with a
 CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException index 10 req with size of 10.

shouldn't putting the showDatabase() at the end of the first PostExecute make it run once after all of the info gets stored in the database? since i'

Comment: Since i'm technically calling the method after all the contents have been retrieved from the nested asynctask?

Comment: At what line exactly you getting the exception ? And try adding c.moveToFirst() immediately after getting cursor instead of writing it later

Comment: After your edit it becomes:

Cursor cursor = query
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
                ( . . . ) (same for articleId, title, url)

                Log.i("id", id);
                (. . .) (same for articleId, title, url)
            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); }

No errors this time and it displays the database info, but as it fills it up because it is in the for loop ...

id 1, id 1 id 2, id 1 id 2 id 3 .... id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: U mean in the while loop right ? What is wrong in that ? all these IDs are coming from webservice right (1-10) ?

Comment: Modify your question and paste your expected output and the output you are getting now

Comment: Alright I've laid out everything, I've also put the whole code with the adjustments you specified.

Comment: Did u try hitting this webservice from restclient ? are u getting the same expected response ?

Comment: I have no clue what a restclient is... so I don't understand the question unfortunately.
How does that work?

Comment: See the logs u have printed are absolutely correct utill the exception ..the are printed repetitive because you are inserting one row and then retrieving and displaying entire table ..also tell me which is exactly is line MainActivity.Java:216

Comment: Line MainActivity.Java:216 is :

Comment: String urlien = String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("url"));

Comment: It seems for 10 ID no value or null is coming in URL ...just add a null check so your application won't crash.. Rest all seems correct..do you have any other concern ?

Comment: Try putting your showdatabase() method now below the for loop after the loop ends in post execute method of DownloadIdList and remove from where it is now.

Comment: I just did and weirdly, it acts as if it hasn't been called at all.
So it just prints the Top Stories Ids and then nothing else

Comment: did u try my updated code ihave made another list idList  and stored values in it.then used it to call webservice